# How to use Latex environment to create a list without line break?

Tags: pdftex

[image]
Like this picture, what I want to creat is

> 13. (a)
>
>     (b)

but not

> 13.(a)
>
> (b)

or

> 13.
>
> (a)
>
> (b).

Also, I don't want to change parameters of packages, for sometimes I like other types of list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I don't really understand what you're doing that is giving you results that aren't exactly like the one in the picture:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \setcounter{enumi}{12}
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Let $H, N$ be normal subgroups of a finite group $G$. Assume that the
    order
    \item Let $H_{1},\dots, H_{r}$ be normal subgroups of $G$ such that the
    order of $H_{i}$ is rel
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]